# Alert or Open login window while switching between application using wpf application

Tags: c#, wpf, process

Let me first explain the scenario:

If in case , I have more than two windows open say for example notepad++,paint,chrome,Skype etc. Now any of the these windows come into focus using ALT+TAB or on left click of mouse. The alert or login window created using wpf should always open.In short it should get alert on each of window come into focus in my computer whether it is notepad++, chrome, vlc or any application listed as open(running application) in task manager.
I tried below code but it throws alert only when any of application is opened for the first time and not while switching between already opened applications so far.

```
    Automation.AddAutomationEventHandler(
                WindowPattern.WindowOpenedEvent,
                AutomationElement.RootElement,
                TreeScope.Children,
                (sender, e) =>
                {
                    var element = sender as AutomationElement;
                    this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                    {
                        this.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen;
                        this.Topmost = true;
                        this.WindowState = System.Windows.WindowState.Normal;

                        MessageBox.Show("window opened");
                    });
```

Hope the point is clear. I m stuck here for switching between the windows scenario. Thanks